# Cheese doesn't record video from my webcam

Tags: usb, 13.10, video, webcam, cheese

Cheese doesn't record video from my webcam... the picture freezes when I press the 'Record a Video' button. If I stop the records, then try and click the record button again it crashes the application.

I'm trying to record video clips using my MS LifeCam with Cheese but it isn't working. I'd really appreciate any help diagnosing and resolving the problem. It can capture photos fine. When I use `lsusb` I can see the camera is detected on the USB bus here:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:0772 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam Studio
```

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 if that's of any use to diagnose this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
```

Then once the install is finished try running cheese.

If this doesn't work I have found the program `guvcview` more stable than cheese for webcam recording.

Comment: I've run that command and I get the following line from the output by apt-get: `gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio is already the newest version.`

Comment: Urg. That is normally the problem. Another option for recording from webcam which I have found more stable than cheese is `guvcview`. Perhaps this works for you. I know it is not a real fix.

Answer (score 0):

I got my Microsoft Lifecam NX-3000 working as follows in (13.10):

Open up the terminal an do the following:

```
echo 'options uvcvideo quirks=0x100' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/uvcvideo.conf
```

See: [www.linux-hardware-guide.com](http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2013-10-16-microsoft-lifecam-nx-3000-usb-webcam)

Comment: Thanks I've tried running what you've suggested by doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to your problem had the same issue with my asus 1015e netbook built in camera, while running Ubuntu 13.10.

At first I thought it was a hardware issue but turns out it is just a resolution problem.

Solution:

1. Go to *Preferences* in Cheese.
2. Change the resolution for the video to anything less than what it is currently set to now.
3. Try it out. Video recording should be possible now without any freezing.

Found the solution at the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1491711)